# Is there a way to update a photo and its message?

Tags: facebook, upload, photo

I'm developing an iOS App which uploads some photos on Facebook.

I'd like to update the photo I uploaded earlier and also its associated message when data is updated in my app. Regarding the Facebook Graph API documentation, I believe there is no permission to do that, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but here's what I gather.

There is a permission that allows you to manage photos, ("user_photos"), which is listed under facebook's permissions reference.

I gather you want to know if there's something that would allow you to update a photo. To my knowledge the answer is no. However, you can easily delete the object instead, and then simply reupload the object, which I gather you've already implemented.

In the Graph API, every photo is an object with a url where it resides, so if you send a 'DELETE' post request to the url, you will be able to delete the photo.

It's described in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ under "Deleting".

Comment: Hi saccharine, thank you for your answer. That's exactly what I want to do. I thought about your solution however if I delete a photo, I think the user will also lose all comments associated with this photo, and I don't want that. I think I will not make a "synchronized" photo album finally and just put the photo on a photo sharing website then post the url to that photo on the user's facebook wall.